# Borel algebra on $\mathbb R$: why not the discrete one?

Tags: measure-theory

I'm only beginning with measure theory so I'm sorry if my question has an obvious and immediate answer. My teacher motivated the introduction of the  Borel algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ by claiming that the discrete $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ is *too big* and that it contains sets that *aren't measurable* and thus we need the more appropriate Borel algebra; but he did not justify this claim. Can someone shed some light on his claim?

Comment: Search Vitali set, Bernstein set, Hamel basis.

Comment: see (e.g. Wikipedia) 'Vitali set'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A $\sigma$-algebra is merely a tool towards defining a measure - which is a function whose domain is the $\sigma$-algebra. The first non-trivial example of a measure you are likely to study is the Lebesgue measure, which generalizes the idea of the length of an interval
$$
l([a,b]) = b-a
$$
The length has a nice property called translation-invariance: ie. if you a shift an interval by a fixed distance $d$, then the length of the new interval $[a+d,b+d]$ is the same as that of $[a,b]$.

This is a desirable property for many reasons, and this restricts the kind of sets that can be "measured". Wait until you come across the standard construction of a non-measurable set. Although that uses the Axiom of Choice, it should indicate why "translation-invariance" does not allow all sets to be measurable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example, which is a minor modification of two well-known constructions:

> There exists a subset of $A$ of  $\Bbb R$ that is both a Vitali set and a Bernstein set.

*Proof.* Let $\mathfrak{c} = \aleph_\alpha$,thus we can define a subset of points of $\Bbb R$ ex post and index all closed sets of $\Bbb R$ ex ante by $\{x_\kappa: \kappa < \aleph_\alpha\}$ and $\{F_\lambda: \lambda < \aleph_\alpha\}$ respectively.

Suppose that, for $\xi < \mathfrak{c}$, $\{x_\lambda : \lambda < \xi\}$ has been defined, and so is $Z_\xi = \bigcup \{x_\lambda + \Bbb Q : \lambda < \xi\}$.

Of course, $|Z_\xi| \leq \max \{ \xi, \aleph_0\} < \mathfrak{c} $ and $|F_\xi| = \mathfrak{c}$(shown by that it contains an isomorphic copy of a Cantor set), so by an uncountable form of $\sf AC$, we're able to choose an element $x_\xi$ from $F_\xi \setminus Z_\xi $. Continuing this process of transfinite recursion lead us to the construction of $A = \{x_\kappa: \kappa < \aleph_\alpha\}$.

*Remark.* $A$ is a Vitali set in the sense that $|A \cap x+\Bbb Q| \leq 1$. $A$ is a Bernstein set in the sense that $A$ doesn't contain any perfect set.